# What is the best method for extracting data from 3D STL models in dentistry?

Tags: 3d

How can I extract measurements data from 3D STL File Format?

in dentistry, Dentists use extraoral scanner to get a 3d model from the patient in which it saved as a STL file format.

I want to know what's the best way to extract data from that model and if I want to compare more than file with each other, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome Mohammed, I believe Blender (it's free) can be used to take measurements from stl models, but I think you'll need to input what the units are of the file you're importing. It looks like it supports importing multiple .stl files as well so you can do comparisons. Just a side note- there may be other forums better suited to answering this type of query.

Comment: Thanks, sir but I have used "blender" I can't compare between vertices because then it might not be compatible so I need a way that I can get precise measurements to get exact data in micrometers

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I'm assuming the compatibility issue you have is when measuring vertices between two imported models? In that situation, I guess you will need to know the relative location (and scale) of one model to the other- with that information there is a Transform you can set on the model node to 'align' the models before measuring. Might be worth asking the question on the blender Forum.